# jQuery Hide All Children of Each Div Except First

Tags: jquery, each

I have this layout:

```
<div class="list">
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to only show the first ul of every div using jQuery. I know it is possible but when using `$('div.list ul:gt(1)').each(function(){$(this).hide()});` it  shows the first div's contents and hides everything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9bEG/3/**

Use this:

```
$("div.list").each(function(){
    $("ul:not(:first)", this).hide();
});
```

It selects each `div` element with class `list`, and hides all `<ul>` elements which are not a first element.

Comment: `$("div.list ul:not(:first-child)").hide()` should work (instead of `:first`).

Comment: Very nice, very nice...now, for the explanation of why the original query doesn't work...maybe the gt(1) is working off the complete list of "ul"s queried?